# fastapi 0.105.0 raised an error: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2),while using celery5.3.6,with centos 7

Tags: celery, fastapi, valueerror

*this is my celery config:*

```
celery = Celery(__name__)
celery.conf.broker_url = os.getenv("BROKER_URL")
celery.conf.result_backend = os.getenv("RESULT_BACKEND")
celery.conf.task_routes = ([
    ("worker_queue.gevent_tasks.*", {"queue": "gevent_queue"}),
    ("worker_queue.prefork_tasks.*", {"queue": "prefork_queue"})
])
```

*this worker method implement(docx_file.py):*

```
def mask_docx_file(upload_file, mask_words, upload_method, mask_method, key, minio_path):
    return "111"
```

*this is celery task(gevent_tasks.py):*

```
@celery.task
def docx_task(upload_file, mask_words, upload_method, mask_method, key, minio_path):
    return mask_docx_file(upload_file, mask_words, upload_method, mask_method, key, minio_path)
```

when i use the task:

```
if file_type == 'docx':
        task_id = docx_task.apply_async((file.filename, keywords, upload_method, mask_method, key, minio_path))
        return task_id.id
```

this is my celery tree

```
fastapi_rebuild/
└── celery_task/
    ├── celery_utils/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── encoding_format.py
    │   ├── key_processor.py
    │   └── minio_operation.py
    ├── worker_queue/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── gevent_tasks.py
    │   └── prefork_tasks.py
    ├── workers/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── docx_file.py
    ├── celery_app.py
```

this line "task_id = docx_task.apply_async((file.filename, keywords, upload_method, mask_method, key, minio_path))" raised the error

this is the error Traceback:

```py
/root/anaconda3/envs/fastapi_rebuild/bin/python /root/Desktop/fastapi_rebuild/main.py 
/root/Desktop/fastapi_rebuild/main.py:22: DeprecationWarning: 
        on_event is deprecated, use lifespan event handlers instead.

        Read more about it in the
        [FastAPI docs for Lifespan Events](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/).
        
  @app.on_event("startup")
INFO:     Started server process [25185]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:9001 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     192.168.18.2:62283 - "POST /mask_file HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/fastapi_rebuild/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 408, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/fastapi_rebuild/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 84, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/fastapi_rebuild/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 1106, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/fastapi_rebuild/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 122, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/fastapi_rebuild/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/fastapi_rebuild/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/fastapi_rebuild/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/fastapi_rebuild/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/fastapi_rebuild/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 20, in __call__
    raise e
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/fastapi_rebuild/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 17, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/fastapi_rebuild/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 718, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/fastapi_rebuild/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 276, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/fastapi_rebuild/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 66, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/fastapi_rebuild/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 274, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/fastapi_rebuild/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 191, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
  File "/root/Desktop/fastapi_rebuild/router/mask_file_router.py", line 54, in test_run_task
    task_id = docx_task.apply_async((file.filename, keywords, upload_method, mask_method, key, minio_path))
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/fastapi_rebuild/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 594, in apply_async
    return app.send_task(
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/fastapi_rebuild/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 728, in send_task
    router = router or amqp.router
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/fastapi_rebuild/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 40, in __get__
    return super().__get__(instance, owner)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/fastapi_rebuild/lib/python3.9/functools.py", line 993, in __get__
    val = self.func(instance)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/fastapi_rebuild/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/app/amqp.py", line 581, in router
    return self.Router()
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/fastapi_rebuild/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/app/amqp.py", line 264, in Router
    return _routes.Router(self.routes, queues or self.queues,
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/fastapi_rebuild/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/app/amqp.py", line 576, in routes
    self.flush_routes()
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/fastapi_rebuild/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/app/amqp.py", line 269, in flush_routes
    self._rtable = _routes.prepare(self.app.conf.task_routes)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/fastapi_rebuild/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/app/routes.py", line 136, in prepare
    return [expand_route(route) for route in routes]
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/fastapi_rebuild/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/app/routes.py", line 136, in <listcomp>
    return [expand_route(route) for route in routes]
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/fastapi_rebuild/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/app/routes.py", line 127, in expand_route
    return MapRoute(route)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/fastapi_rebuild/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/app/routes.py", line 33, in __init__
    for k, v in map:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

please tell me what's the probelem ,thanks

i tried docx_task.apply_async and docx_task.delay,it raised the same error

Comment: Add full error message to your question (all Traceback)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I've updated my question with the full error message and traceback.

Comment: i solved this probelm,the celery config "task_routes" should be like this :celery.conf.task_routes = {
    "worker_queue.gevent_tasks.*": {"queue": "gevent_queue"},
    "worker_queue.prefork_tasks.*": {"queue": "prefork_queue"}
}